# Template in HTML, with Webpack, get error "variable" is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, lodash

I created template in index.html to generate html-code with js, code below. My Webpack configuration also below. When I run it with webpack-dev-server, I get error: title is not defined. Somehow webpack tries to resolve 'title' by self, instead of delegate it to 'lodash/template'. Please help me fix code, I'm in despair(.

```js
import path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob';
import webpack from 'webpack';

import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const inProduction = process.env.mode === 'production';

export default {
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/scripts/main.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: inProduction,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

```js
import temp from 'lodash/template'
import data from './data';

const titlePicDiscHalf = temp(document.getElementById('titlePicDiscHalf').innerHTML);
document.write(titlePicDiscHalf({ title: 'Hello World!' }));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/template" id="titlePicDiscHalf">
      <div class="titlePicDiscHalf">
        <div class="picture"></div>
        <div class="title"><%=title%></div>
        <div class="discription"></div>
        <div class="buttons"></div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `<%=` and `%>` delimirters used by template.

Comment: @dfsq, if I change it to other symbols like `<$=title$>`, no errors, but it render `<$=title$>`, instead "Hello world"

Comment: `html-webpack-plugin` uses the same templating syntax. Maybe the error comes from the plugin trying to resolve title?

Comment: @lukas-reineke yes, this is exactly the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that html-webpack-plugin uses the same template tags `<%= %>` to insert bundle information into template.

You have two options.

#### 1. Change lodash.template delimiters

You could change delimiters used by client-side lodash/template to something else, so Webpack would ignore it. For example:

```
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /<\$=([\s\S]+?)\$>/g;
```

Check out this demo.

```js
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /<\$=([\s\S]+?)\$>/g;

const temp = _.template
const titlePicDiscHalf = temp(document.getElementById('titlePicDiscHalf').innerHTML);

document.write(titlePicDiscHalf({ title: 'Hello World!' }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="titlePicDiscHalf">
  <div class="titlePicDiscHalf">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <$=title$>
    </div>
    <div class="discription"></div>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

### 2. Change html-webpack-plugin delimiters

Install `ejs-loader` separately and configure `html-webpack-plugin` to use it to load your template. There you can change delimiters to yours. It could look something like this:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './index.html.ejs',
  })
],
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.ejs$/, loader: 'ejs-loader', query: {
      interpolate: /<\$=([\s\S]+?)\$>/g,
      evaluate: /<\$([\s\S]+?)\$>/g,
    }},
  ]
},
```

Now, you can configure your template with two different set of delimiters, one for client bundle lodash template and another for `html-webpack-plugin`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><$= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title $></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/template" id="titlePicDiscHalf">
      <div class="titlePicDiscHalf">
        <div class="picture"></div>
        <div class="title"><%= title %></div>
        <div class="discription"></div>
        <div class="buttons"></div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, `<title><$= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title $></title>` is used by webpack, and `<div class="title"><%= title %></div>` is by client-side lodash.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it possible instead of changing lodash syntax change webpack syntax settings?

Comment: @dfsq hello. thank you for your answer. If I use format <%- configuration %> how should I write regex for ejs-loader? this interpolate: /<\$-([\s\S]+?)\$>/g, does not work for me

Comment: @runia it should be `interpolate: <%-([\s\S]+?)%>` and `evaluate: /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,`.

Comment: @runia Okay, did you try what I posted in answer with `<$=`?

Comment: @dfsq I use <%- configuration %> in my .ejs file.
I tried interpolate: '<\$=([\\s\\S]+?)\$>',
                    evaluate: /<\$([\s\S]+?)\$>/g

Does not work for me. After I tried interpolate : "<%-([\s\S]+?)%>",
                    evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g . Does not work too. I get error ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: configuration is not defined. I use your 2 item. (Change html-webpack-plugin delimiters)

Comment: @dfsq when I try this interpolate : "<%-([\s\S]+?)%>",
                    evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g I get error Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: @runia Okay, I see what the problem is. If you want to use `<%- %>` delimiters to interpolate, then you also need to change escape delimiters because by default `<%-` is used for escaping. So do this `interpolate: /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g, evaluate: /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g, escape: /<%\:-(.*?)\:\%>/g,`. Finally, if you want some custom variables like configuration, it needs to be used like `<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.configuration %>` in template.

Comment: @dfsq thanks, but I get the same error ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: configuration is not defined. I cannot use htmlWebpackPlugin.options because I generate and inlcude configuration from nodejs server express (app.render)

Comment: @runia You can't use some global variable in `<%- %>`, won't work. You will have to provide them with `html-webpack-plugin` config in webpack, and than access those within `htmlWebpackPlugin.options` namespace.

Comment: @dfsq can you give us more details?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else falls in the same trap where one simply wants to use a static html file with some `<script>` inside and subsequently encountering an error like `Referenceerror: variable is not defined`.

Make sure you are not using JS template strings!

E.g. instead of doing something like

```
function addLoginStatus(user) {
    document.querySelector('.login-status').textContent = `You logged in as user.firstName`;
}
```

use something like this:

```
function addLoginStatus(user) {
    document.querySelector('.login-status').textContent = 'You logged in as ' + user.firstName;
}
```

I found that with template strings, the `webpack-html-plugin` template will naturally try to interpret them, which was not intended in my case.